# Questions about verbs

Tags: verbs, usage, american-english, subject-verb-agreement

> 70% (700) of the total data is used as training data, and the remaining 20% (200) **are used as** validation data.

I am in the process of creating presentation PPT materials.

Is *are used as* correct in this sentence? So why not use *is used as*?

And in English, isn't there a unit when writing down the number of data? I wonder if I can just set it to 700 and 200.

Comment: No: "is used as" is correct in both clauses. _Percent_ is best analysed here as a noun taking an _of_ complement. It belongs with the number-transparent nouns, where the number of the whole NP is determined by the number of the NP that is complement of the prep "of". In this case, the complement of "of" is the singular "the total data", and hence the whole NP is singular for agreement purposes. The values in brackets are simply interpolations and are not involved in determining number agreement.

Comment: Note that some speakers think of *data* as a count noun (they’d say things like “the data **are** compelling”), though most think of it as a mass noun (for them it would be “the data **is** compelling”).

Comment: And of course, @BillJ is using *interpolations* in its linguistic sense, not its mathematical sense.

Comment: What happened to the other 10%? 70% + 20% is only 90%. It should be **remaining 30%(300)**.